# Not all intents working with native iOS Twitter app

Tags: ios, twitter, hyperlink, safari

Setting any of these as an href on an anchor tag in mobile Safari launches the Twitter native app, but does not perform the intent (intents taken from [web intent docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)):

```
twitter://tweet?in_reply_to=51113028241989632
twitter://retweet?tweet_id=51113028241989632
twitter://favorite?tweet_id=51113028241989632
```

However, this works as expected:

```
twitter://user?user_id=32904374
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web intents are for the web (i.e. a browser), but are not the same as custom url schemes, which you are showing here. The Twitter custom url schemes are officially unpublished, but some people have reverse engineered them here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Twitter

Try this: `twitter://post?in_reply_to_status_id=51113028241989632`

I couldn't find retweet or favorite but you might be able to with some digging around.